# jqGrid get rowid of master grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

In the AfterSaveFunction of a subgrid I want to known the rowId of the parent grid (in order to update a cell on that row), however the following gives a null value:

```
function SubgridAfterSave(rowid, data) { 
    var masterRowId = $("#master").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
    ...
}
```

Perhaps null is returned as a subgrid row is selected (inline edit) and not a (master) grid row. Is there another way to get the rowId of the master grid, or do I have to supply it in the data parameter? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is the master row physically selected (highlighted) when you try this?

Comment: No, it is not. A row in the detail grid is selected (as it is edited). As a "workaround" I supply the master rowId in the data parameter (set by the server).

Comment: Perhaps you can try this option in your parent grid: `selectOnExpand:true`. It’s a bit hard to figure out, since you posted very little code, so we don’t know how your grid actually looks like.

Comment: Does that work if more than one row is expanded, and the edit action is not on a subgrid of the last expanded row?